# Why is the following true? $\operatorname{rank}(A^G A) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, generalized-inverse

I saw the following theorem in my text book:

> If $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix with $n \geq m$ then
>
> $$\operatorname{rank}(A^G A) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$$

**Note**: $A^G$ here is the **generalized** inverse of $A$.

I'm trying to understand why this is and would really appreciate it if someone could prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by definition of $A^G$, we have $AA^GA=A$ and by the general properties of rank with respect to products, the rank of $A^GA$ lies between the rank of $A$ and the rank of $AA^GA$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. "The general properties of rank with respect to products"? Can you please elaborate on that bit

Comment: @RyanJ Certainly. The rank of a product of matrices is at most equal to the smallest rank of the factor matrices, and specifically it's at most equal to the rank of a specific factor (I find it easiest to show this by looking at the dimension of images / kernels: the dimension of the image of a linear map cannot possibly increase by composing the map with another map, and the dimension of the kernel cannot possibly decrease). Thus the rank of $A^GA$ is at most equal to the rank of $A$, and the rank of $A(A^GA)$ is at most equal to the rank of $A^GA$.